# How do I do a universal SOQL?

Tags: trigger, error, error-messages, before-trigger

I made a Trigger for an Object1 that gets Id from Object2. Rather, Object1 entries already have Object2 IDs, but now I need to make a lookup based on it. The Object2 can be any object you want: system or custom. So, how can I write the universal SOQL for my Map? Now I have this one:

```
Map<Id, Object> tMap = new Map<Id, Object>([SELECT Id FROM Object]);
```

My errors are: `Invalid type: Schema.Object` and `Variable does not exist: Id`.
All I need to do this:

```
trigger ToolsObjTrigger on Tool__c (before insert) {
    for(Tool__c t : Trigger.new){
        if(!String.isEmpty(t.textId__c)){
            Id neededId = Id.valueOf(t.textId__c);
            String objectAPIName  = neededId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;
            Map<Id, SObject> objectsMap = new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + objectAPIName ));      
            if(objectsMap.get(t.textId__c).Id != null && objectAPIName == 'Obj__c'){
                t.Obj__c = objectsMap.get(t.textId__c).Id;
            }  
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you've created a sort of synthetic polymorphic lookup? That is, a text field on `Tool_c` that holds the Id of some other record, of any type?

Comment: Yes. There can be any object Id. It's a text field only.

Comment: And what is the field `Obj__c`? Is that a lookup relationship?

Comment: Yes, it's our lookup.

Comment: A lookup to what object? As far as I know, you still cannot create your own polymorphic lookups.

Comment: A lookup to the record with that Id. And it can be any object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to get the object's type from the ID then use this in the dynamic SOQL. For example:

```
Id id = Id.valueOf(tool.cId__c);

String objectAPIName = id.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;

List<SObject> matches = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + objectAPIName + ' WHERE Id = :id');
```

Bulkification is possible, but worst case you need n separate queries for n separate IDs where the types are all different. The idea would be to build a map of objectAPIName to list of IDs, like:

```
Map<Id, List<Id>> idsByObjectAPIName = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

for (Tool__c tool : Trigger.new) {
    Id id = Id.valueOf(tool.cId__c);
    String objectAPIName = id.getSobjectType().getDescribe().name;

    List<Id> idsForId = idsByObjectAPIName.get(objectAPIName);

    if (idsForId == null) {
        idsByObjectAPIName.put(objectAPIName, new List<Id> { id });
    else {
        idsForId.add(id);
    }
}
```

At this point you can then iterate the map by key set to perform the various queries, though if there are too many object types you will get a too many queries error:

```
for (String objectAPIName : idsByObjectAPIName.keySet()) {
    List<Id> ids = idsByObjectAPIName.get(objectAPIName);

    // Query the objects, with whatever fields you need for this object type
    List<SObject> theObjects = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + objectAPIName + ' WHERE Id IN :ids');

    // Do what you need
}
```

If your trigger is being called from a batch, and you don't have other types of bulk change, you can control the maximum possible number of different object types, by controlling the number of Tool__c instances that are processed together. This is done using the scope size parameter on [Database.executeBatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm). If you know you can safely handle 50 (say) types of object, just set the scope size to 50. After all, the most cId__c values you can have is one per Tool__c instance, and the most different types you can then have is one per cId__c value.

Comment: This is correct. But it would be very hard to bulkify. Imagine the trigger being called with 150 records, each pointing towards a different object. You would end up executing 150 unique queries.

Comment: Thank you for help. It works! I updated my code. Can you tell me please how to remove the Map with SOQL from the loop in this case?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm):

```
String type = 'Abc__c';
Map<Id, SObject> m = new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + type));
```

Also see the [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) documentation for methods to access the data.

By taking these approaches, the types involved only matter at runtime, not at compile time. But you naturally do lose compile-time type checking.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm really not sure how to set the type. In the field can be any Object Id. So we have to search it by Id in all database.

Comment: See the `getSobjectType()` method available on `Id` in Phil W's answer; very handly for this context. But if you have many `Id` values you will need to work out the set of types and do a query per type.